# "Времена" - уместно ли в репортажах?

Tags: стилистика

Когда спортивные комментаторы говорят о результатах спортсмена, они нередко употребляют слово "времена". Речь, как понятно, идет о разных достижениях - то есть, сегодня спортсмен, например, пробежал дистанцию за 2 минуты, а вчера - за полторы.
Честно говоря, в данном контексте слово "времена" несколько режет слух, потому что привычнее его слышать по отношению к грамматической категории, либо с оттенков высокопарности: "О времена, о нравы!"

Comment: В каком контексте комментаторы употребляют слово ВРЕМЕНА? Приведите пример,. пожалуйста. Мы не можем ответить, так как вопрос неясен.

Comment: Да, действительно. Суть вопроса неясна. Приведите, пожалуйста, пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существительное "время" имеет категорию мн.числа в значении периода времени ("былые времена") или в грамматическом значении ("используются разные времена").

В спорте следует говорить о разных результатах, например: Спортсмен показывает разные результаты. Обычно понятно, о каких результатах идет речь.

Если всё-таки требуется уточнить, какой именно результат, то можно сказать так:

"За это команда была оштрафована 1200 очками и, хотя показала лучший результат по времени, отлично выполнив остальные этапы, оказалась лишь на 5-м месте".

Comment: София, дело не в результатах, это и так понятно. А насколько я понял,  возможно ли употребить "времена", говоря, например, о тех же самых результатах. Я тоже считаю некорректным употреблять мн.ч. в этой области. Лучше: в разное время спортсмены достигали разных результатов. Т.е. ед.ч. вместо мн.ч.

Comment: Я как раз обозначила две темы, когда можно применить мн. число. В остальных случаях форма мн. числа не используется и заменяется другими выражениями.

Comment: Насчет примеров позволю себе вмешаться. Комментаторы действительно употребляют это слово, говоря о спортивных показателях. Что-то вроде "времена спортсменов-бегунов стали лучше" - то есть, время, за которое они пробегают определенную дистанцию сократилось.

Comment: Это ошибка комментаторов. Время одно, у каждого свое. А приведенное вами предложение уже некорректно.